# Add Module Dependancy in Groovy/Grails application with Intellij

Tags: grails, module, intellij-idea, dependency-management

environment: Intellij 11.1.

I have a groovy module, lets say **MyGroovyModule**, and a grails application **MyGrailsApp**.

What i need is to add a dependancy from my grails app to groovy module.

Steps:

1. Right click on grails app
2. Open module settings
3. On Dependancies tab, add a module Dependancy and select the MyGroovyModule

The grails app compiles fine, however when im trying to startup the app or create the .war file, it fails with error:

`unable to resolve class` ...

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the dependency in IntelliJ is doing just that.  It does not add the dependency to your Grails application.  You're really just adding to the classpath.  What you need to do is add the dependency via Grails which probably means one of the following:

- Build the JAR and drop it in your Grails app's lib folder
- Make your module a Grails plugin and add it as a dependency via BuildConfig.groovy
- Push your module to a local maven/ivy repository and then add the dependency using BuildConfig.groovy
- Push your module to a public/private maven repository located on a server and then add the dependency using the BuildConfig.groovy
- Make your Groovy Module part of your grails app (add all the code to the src or utils folder)